# Web browser | Disabling the download of arbitrary scripts

Tags: firefox, security, browser, javascript

I use firefox. Is there an addon or setting to stop my browser from downloading all the scripts that are linked on a webpage?
I would like to only follow links which are at domains in my whitelist.
I already use noscript, but I would prefer to not open any http connections to untrusted links at all.
Also, regardless of the above, I would like to have the option of allowing specific scripts as opposed to all scripts from a domain.

Comment: Adblock Plus can be used in this way. It's designed to block "ads", but it can actually block any generic HTTP request. If a request that's about to be sent matches any of the filters, the request is never sent to the server.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you've checked this out, but the [ABE](http://noscript.net/abe/) is a sort of addon to NoScript that provides additional firewall-like functionality; this may be closer to what you want.

Comment: @allquixotic Except that with Adblock Plus, there will be a HTTP connection for the page itself, as the filters work only for elements in the page, not the page itself. I was going to suggest Request Policy, but as far as I can tell, same problem.

Comment: @rhill I think adblock plus rules could be made to work, but I haven't tried it myself. They have rules for blocking specific file types, and rules for making "exceptions"; all you have to do is make a really restrictive blacklist rule that encapsulates all the things you want to block, and then make exceptions for things you want to allow which are matched by the blacklist. If you block things by URL or domain, Adblock Plus will **not** send a request for that URL to the remote host. Requests only have to be sent for element based (DOM-based) blocking.

Comment: @allquixotic according to ABP documentation, blacklisting a whole page doesn't work, as the $document option is enforced only for whitelist filters. See https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#options . There is a blog post somewhere in which the author explains the rationale (it used to work in the past), but I didn't save the link.

Comment: Would [HTTP Nowhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-nowhere/) be helpful??

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is NoScript:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

Comment: His question says "I already use NoScript". Did you not see that part?

Comment: LOL for some reason I assumed he was already running NoAds... Yes, that's my bad.